# How to access ActivityMainBinding file from fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, tabs, android-viewbinding

I MainActivity where I have bottom navigation tabs. And I have a fragment where I need to have access to the ActivityMainBinding file to change the state of the bottom tab.
Could you please show me how to get a reference to ActivityMainBinding from a fragment to use the following code?

```
binding.bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(UiResources.rooms_navigation).setChecked(true)
```

Comment: You shouldn't. Period.

Comment: Why this scenario particularly?! Just make a method on your activity to handle the state changes and call it from your child fragment using `requireActivity`.